# Embed JS window height to CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, slider

I´m trying to fix a slider issue. The slider should be 100% windowsize - header & footer. So I´ve setup JS to load windowheight and normally it should set the information in CSS. Here is my problem - as it seems it doesn't have any effect at all.  This is my JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sliderheight() {
        var windowheight = $(window).height();
        $(".cycle-slideshow").delay(500).css("height", windowheight);
        $(".slides").delay(500).css("height", windowheight);
        $("#wrapper").delay(500).css("height", windowheight);
        $(".slides .slide-thumb").delay(500).css("height", windowheight);
        $("#rsts-crop").delay(500).css("height", windowheight);     
    };

    $(window).load(function() {
        sliderheight();
    });
</script>
```

Each of these containers needs to be resized (it's just a worpress-theme). 
You can have a look here: [Slider](http://soendgerath.contact1.info/)

Comment: Remove the `;` from the end of the first function. May not fix it, but it isn't needed.

Comment: @dwreck08 That's not an issue here

Comment: `delay()` works with queue, you aren't putting anything in queue

Comment: Right, but it gives a JS warning.

Comment: nope thats not the problem:) But thx anyway @dwreck08

Comment: try (windowheight+"px")

Comment: or try that: `getWindowWidth: function () {
        var w = window,
            d = document,
            e = d.documentElement,
            g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        return w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth;
    }`

Comment: also you do need those delays if there are all the same. get rid of them and use a timeout function -- function sliderheight(){
 //the code in here
}   -- in your win load function   -- setTimeout(sliderheight, 500);

Comment: and you can also change the height like this--  $(".cycle-slideshow").height(windowheight);  --  without using that long css clause -- https://jsfiddle.net/rttsL1t4/

Comment: Ok, so i´ve added +"px". But I´m not sure if i did it right. I also added a preloader to solve the delay () problem. (Like this, `$("#loader").delay(500).fadeOut();  $(".slides").delay(500).css("height", windowheight+"px"); `how do I add timeout function? Sorry I´m just learning JS

Comment: last tip. you can chain all those elements to one -- $(".cycle-slideshow, .slides, #wrapper, .slides .slide-thumb,  #rsts-crop").height(windowheight);  - so you can do it in one line  -- https://jsfiddle.net/L7pxtrb5/

Comment: Looks great. I´will try to get it to work- THX

Comment: I dont get it to work. So now i´ve just copied your codes. (everything) and all I see is a black line at the top left corner of my slider. JS works, I tested via Alert - but .box wont take the height. Maybe its something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it

```
jQuery(".cycle-slideshow, #slide-wrap, .slides, .slides > div:first, .slides > div:first *, .slides .slide-thumb").css("height", jQuery(window).height());
```

or

```
$(".cycle-slideshow, #slide-wrap, .slides, .slides > div:first, .slides > div:first *, .slides .slide-thumb").css("height", $(window).height());
```

But I would recommend you to configure the height with CSS.

Does it help you?